# Check when Faye has finished the publish function

Tags: node.js, faye

I'm quite new to working with Faye and I have a small question concerning it. I'm trying to call a redirect function to another page after I publish a string with Faye.

The problem is: the redirect mostly happens before Faye has gotten the chance to make it's connections and send it to the channel.

My question is: is there a way to check when Faye has succesfully published something and execute a function afterwards?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to check if publishing a message has been successful or not:

```
var publication = client.publish('/foo', {text: 'Hi there'});

publication.then(function() {
  // OK
}, function(error) {
  // NOT OK, redirect
});
```

This one is [documented](http://faye.jcoglan.com/browser/publishing.html).

Comment: I feel like an idiot for looking over something like that :/ Thanks for the answer!